# Difficulty with dictionary in RPG Script

Tags: python

I am writing a function that will be used in a RPG that will take a character's stat sheet and return a the characters "Dexterity" stat.

Write a function named "get_stat" that takes a key-value store as a parameter with strings as keys and integers as values. The keys include "Strength", "Constitution", "Defense", "Dexterity", "Intelligence", "Charisma", "Willpower", and "Luck" and each value is an integer between 0 and 255. This function should return the value for the "Dexterity" stat.

```
def get_stat(key_values): 
    key_values = ({ "Strength": 10, "Constitution": 10, "Defense": 10, "Dexterity": 10, "Intelligence": 10, "Charisma": 10, "Willpower": 10,"Luck": 10}) 
    for i in key_values:
         if i == "Dexterity": 
             return key_values.get("Dexterity")
```

How can I make "Dexterity" equal to an integer between 0 and 225? So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Inputing [{'Willpower': 252, 'Dexterity': 209, 'Luck': 162, 'Charisma': 17, 'Strength': 189, 'Defense': 229, 'Constitution': 103, 'Intelligence': 176}] should return 209 instead of 10.

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding the `key_values` argument passed to the `get_stat` function by assigning to `key_values` a new dict that has all values set to `10`, so it naturally returns a dexterity value of 10 no matter what `key_values` you pass to it. You should instead return the value of the `Dexterity` key from the `key_values` argument directly:

```
def get_dexterity(key_values):
    return key_values.get("Dexterity")
```

so that with:

```
key_values = { "Strength": 103, "Constitution": 210, "Defense": 192, "Dexterity": 255, "Intelligence": 80, "Charisma": 25, "Willpower": 36,"Luck": 191}
print(get_dexterity(key_values))
```

this outputs:

```
255
```